# .htaccess whitelist IP exept 1 file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a internal website which has a `.htaccess` login except for the office IP. Which IP is white listed. Now I need a cronjob to get a file but I don't want normal users to access that file directly. An overview:

```
- public_html/
  - index.php
  - files.php
  - all_folders/
  - cronjob_only/dump.sql
```

So all users can access all, except `cronjob_only/dump.sql`. If they are inside the office they don't require a login. Outside they need to login.
The `cronjob_only/dump.sql` always requires a login and a the valid user `cron_user`

I did get it working without the ip whitelisting. My .htaccess file:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/admin/domains/website.com/.htpasswd-file
AuthName "U shall not pass"


Allow from 94.215.167.79 #office IP
require valid-user
Satisfy Any

<FilesMatch "dump.sql">
  Require user cron_user
</FilesMatch>
```

The above allows people inside the ip to access the dump.sql
If I turn off the `Allow from..` the login split works.

What am I missing? I tried a lot. Most of it found here on stackoverflow.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<FilesMatch "dump.sql">
  Order allow,deny
  Require user cron_user
  Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>
```

Please note that I'm not sure of this answer.

Comment: Yes this works. And if you add code that should be an answer. Even if you're not sure. Just say you're not sure, I do it all the time. Or just say _should work, not tested_